# Access 2003: Determine whether one or all of 4 fields exist in table

Tags: ms-access

I have a table which changes every day but will always have the same name (Scrubbed). I need a query to determine whether the new fields exist in the table that day. I'll call them field1, field2, field3, field4.

I had a sql query:

```
SELECT Scrubbed.field1, Scrubbed.field2, Scrubbed.field3, Scrubbed.field4
FROM Scrubbed;
```

Which errors with a message box (new fields not in table) if it doesn't find all 4 fields. This isn't working out. If the table contains fields 1 and 2 but not 3 and 4, I need the user to know that without opening the table.

Comment: I believe you'll need to resort to VBA for this.  Likely TableDef.

Comment: The table structure changes **every day**?

Comment: No, for that one I ended up creating an error message if the query failed. Will that FieldExists() function work to look for 4 separate fields? Yes, the table changes more than once a day which has created many challenges in setting up queries that will always work.

Comment: You can select all 4 fields as I demonstrated and that will fail if any one of them is missing.